# How to create users in collabnet?

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn, collabnet

I am working on **collabnet subversion repository**. I installed **CollabNetSubversionEdge-4.0.6_setup-x86_64** software and I created users in Collabnet **GUI** to access my repository. And I and my users accessing my repository and everything is working fine.**But**,

Here my task is **Insted of creating users in Collabnet Create users in Data base(MySql or Oracle) and make them to lo-gin from our DataBase to access collabnet**

I googled a lot but I didn't get even a single  answer for this one.**May be this is not possible**. If it possible please tell me how to achieve this one.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion passes off security to its servers. If you use Apache `httpd` (you don't specify), you can use whatever Apache configurations to do user access. The two most common is LDAP (which can connect to your Windows Active Directory server) and using a text based `httpasswd` to generate a user password file. I have not seen this with SQL, and I couldn't imagine why you'd want to use something so complex for something so simple -- unless you already store users in a SQL database.

If nothing else, you could have a crontab that would build the `svn_access_file` via a SQL query that runs it through `httpasswd`.

There is some information from [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/portal.1014/b19305/cg_app_e.htm) on this, but I have never seen it done, and Apache httpd's documentation doesn't have specific directions.